# NumPy memmap slow loading small chunk from large file on first read only

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-memmap

I am using NumPy memmap to load a small amount of data from various locations throughout a large binary file (memmap'd, reshaped, flipped around, and then around 2000x1000 points loaded from around a 2 GB binary file). There are five 2 GB files each with its own memory map object.

The memory maps are created all very quickly.  And the slice of data from the first several files pulls out very quickly.  But, then, it suddenly stops on the fourth and fifth file.  Memory usage remains low, so, it does not appear to be reading the whole file into memory, but, I/O access from the process is high.  It could easily take ten or fifteen minutes for this to clear, and then everything proceeds as expected.  Subsequent access through all of the memory maps is extremely rapid, including loading data that was not previously touched.  Memory usage remains low throughout.  Closing Python and re-running, the problem does not reoccur until reboot (caching maybe?).

I'm on Windows 10 with Python 2.7.  Any thoughts for troubleshooting?

EDIT:  There was a request in the comments for file format type and example code.  Unfortunately, I cannot provide exact details; however, I can say this much.  The file format contains just int16 binary values for a 3D array which can be reshaped by the format [n1, n2, n3] where n* are the length for each dimension.  However, the files are split at 2GB.  So, they are loaded in like this:

```
memmaps = []
for filename in filelist:
    memmaps.append(np.memmap(filename, dtype=np.int16, mode='r'))
    memmaps[-1] = memmaps[-1].reshape([len(memmaps[-1])/n2/n3, n2, n3])
    memmaps[-1] = np.transpose(memmaps[-1], [2,1,0])
```

This certainly isn't the cleanest code in the world, but it generally works, except for this seemingly random slow down.  The user has a slider which allows them to plot a slice from this array as

```
image = np.zeros([n2, n1], dtype=np.int16)
#####
c = 0
for d in memmaps:
    image[:,c:(c+d.shape[2])] = d[slice,:,:]
    c = c + d.shape[2]
```

I'm leaving out a lot of detail, but I think this captures the most relevant information.

EDIT 2:  Also, I am open to alternative approaches to handling this problem.  My end goal is real time interactive plotting of an arbitrary and relatively small chunk of 2D data as an image from a large 3D dataset that may be split across multiple binary files.  I'm presently using pyqtgraph with fairly reasonable results, except for this random problem.

Comment: "memmap'd, reshaped, flipped around" - sounds like you're loading non-contiguous data from the fourth and fifth files. Think about what disk access patterns you're generating.

Comment: Also yeah, there's plenty of caching.

Comment: To clarify... I'm loading non-contiguous data from all five files.  The only loads that are extremely slow are the first reads from the fourth and fifth file.  All previous and subsequent loads are basically instantanious.  Fast enough that I can plot the data in real time as the user drags a slider which determines which slices to display.

Comment: Actually, one other relevant piece of information.  HD I/O speed is on the order of 3 MB/s while the file it is sticking on is being read.  This would be indicative of the whole file being loaded into cache at a very slow speed (it's not being reported as memory usage anyway -- memory usage is reported around 60 MB the entire time python is running).  Perhaps the slowdown isn't Python related, but should it be reading the entire file?

Comment: Can you show an example of the code and the file format?

Comment: Added some details on file format and example of code!

Comment: I wanted to add one more comment.  This is only an issue on Windows.  On Linux, this behavior has not yet been observed.

Comment: Scratch my previous comment.  This is definitely happening on Linux too, but just not as bad.  The Linux machine is a much more powerful computer.  So, I guess my suspicion is now out of order HD access.  I'll try on an SSD to see what happens.  I'm wondering about rethinking how the data is loaded.  I'm pulling it into another NumPy array for further manipulation, so, why not just populate the array out of order so that I can read the file in a linear fashion, skipping data that is not needed?